# Selenium: stop loop once element is class is disabled

Tags: python, selenium

Currently trying to loop through all the pages on this website:

- https://ephisahs.microsoftcrmportals.com/disclaimer/restaurantinspections/south-facilities/

When it reaches page 53 (end of the page), it continues to loop even though there are no more pages. How can I make the loop stop? I notice that the element class ="disabled" appears.

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.get('https://ephisahs.microsoftcrmportals.com/disclaimer/restaurantinspections/south-facilities/')

dfs = []
page_counter = 0
while True:

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[@data-name]")))
    cards = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[@data-name]")
    facilities = []
    for card in cards:
        name = card.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-th='Unit Name']").text
        street1 = card.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-th='Site Street 1']").text
        street2 = card.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-th='Site Street 2']").text
        site_city = card.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-th='Site City']").text
        site_prov = card.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-th='Site Province/State']").text
        site_code = card.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-th='Site Postal Code/Zip Code']").text
        site_fac = card.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-th='Facility Category']").text
        site_inspection = card.find_element_by_xpath(".//td[@data-th='Inspections Completed']").text
        ref_link = card.find_element_by_xpath(".//td//a").get_attribute("href")
        
        facilities.append([name, street1, street2, site_city,site_prov,site_code,site_fac,site_inspection,ref_link])

    df = pd.DataFrame(facilities)    
    dfs.append(df)
    
    print(page_counter)
    page_counter+=1
    try:
        wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[aria-label='Next page']"))).click()
    
    except:
        break
        
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: please paste the code snippet.

Comment: What have you attempted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply check the class of the `li` element **as mentioned in the doc**

```
is_disabled = "disabled" in element.get_attribute("class")    
if is_disabled:
        break
```

> `is_active = "active" in target_element.get_attribute("class")`
>
> https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute